# How to implement Vector Auto-Regression in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting, statsmodels

I want to implement **vector autoregression** in python. My data is saved as a list of 3 lists. I found this - 
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/vector_ar.html#var, but could not figure out the proper way to implement.

Suppose *tsdata* - a list of 3 lists of length 100 each, is my data. I tried

```python
varmodel = ts.VAR(tsdata)

results = varmodel.fit(maxlags=5, ic='aic')
```

But the above is not working.

**Update**:
I have changed the list of lists to a column stack according to suggestions below. It is working fine now. So tsdata, which was a list of lists is changed to

```
tsdata  = np.column_stack(tsdata)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "it is not working." When I execute ``VAR(data_as_lists).fit(maxlags=5, ic='aic').summary()`` I get output -- unclear whether said output is sensible. Even so, your data should probably be a pandas DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex.

Comment: my guess is that it's because a list of list has the wrong shape, variables are in rows and observation in columns, when it is converted to an array. try np.column_stack on the list of lists

Comment: Where is `tsdata` in your code? You mention it in the question, but all I see is `resid`.

Comment: It should have been tsdata in the code as well. Corrected the typo. Will try np.column_stack.

Comment: Philip, thanks for your suggestions. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the list of lists to a column stack ([as @Josef suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348720/how-to-implement-vector-auto-regression-in-python#comment26955958_18348720)) may solve your problem. For that, one might use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) as follows

```
tsdata  = np.column_stack(tsdata)
```